# Escape = False On OutputText Not Rendering HTML In RichText

Tags: visualforce, html, outputtext, richtextarea

I am trying to render some HTML stored within a custom sObject's a richText field.

I am using an outputText field as follows:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Information.Content__c}" escape="false"/>
```

The field contains the following:

> `<code> CoolCodeExample codeExample = new CoolCodeExample(); </code>`

However, it is not being rendered as HTML.

When I inspected it in the browser, the `<code>` tag is being wrapped with double quotes.

Anyway I can have this properly rendered in HTML? I imagine it is something mundane I've overlooked. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Any reason why you go with output text .Go with outputfield instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per doc:  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_using_rich_text_area.htm&language=en_US

> HTML code is not supported in the Salesforce HTML editor. HTML code is
>   treated as text.

Using a `Long Text Area` field with

`<apex:outputText value="{!Information.LongTextField__c}" escape="false"/>` works.

Comment: Like I thought, some mundane detail I missed. Thank you very much.