# How to apply CSS styles to a Rich text field in a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, stylesheets

I have a Object 'A' with field 'testField1' and it has html formatted text value..

Something like this:

```
testField1 = "<div class="text">sample text </div><div class = "boldthis"> bold this text</div>"
```

I have overriden the object detail page for object A with visualforce page and it has style attributes, so how do i apply these styles for the field "testField1" on the detail page?

I am trying to do with `<apex:outputText value="{!A.testField1}">` but it is just printing raw html text?

Comment: What is type of your field ? As per this answer, [Type of field supported is Long Text Area][1]. 


  [1]: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46176/escape-false-on-outputtext-not-rendering-html-in-richtext

Comment: It is rich text field

Comment: As per this documentation it seems Containt in Rich text area is saved as Text, I would suggest to use Text Area. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_using_rich_text_area.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question implies that the HTML markup is being shown onscreen.

If that's the case, you can use the `escape` attribute on the `outputText` tag and VisualForce will not convert the values from the text into the HTML entities when rendering the markup.

Documentation: [`<apex:outputText />`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm)

Example:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!A.testField1}" escape="false" />
```

Comment: Note that if you're planning on releasing this code as part of a managed package that the use of `escape="false"` will you mean you fail security review.